# Unable to assign row count to variable in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I am trying to assign the number of row as integer to a variable in plpgsql 9.1.
Try 1: nothing gets assigned

```
maz int := (SELECT count(col1) FROM table WHERE col1 = quote_literal(val1));
```

Try 2: getting error near INTO

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(col1) FROM table
         WHERE col1 = quote_literal(val1) INTO maz';
```

<sup>EDIT: deleted "in" as it was a typo.</sup>

Comment: You would have to post a *complete* function definition including the header, to be clear here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your examples are little bit messy.

The first example is wrong - probably incorrect use of `IN` keyword, and `quote_literal()` is absolutely useless in this context. The second one is probably wrong too - if `val1` is a variable. plpgsql variables are not visible inside the SQL string in an `EXECUTE` statement. Next issue is `INTO` in the SQL string.

```
postgres=# do $$
           DECLARE rc int;
                   val1 varchar := 'Hello'; 
           BEGIN
             rc := (SELECT count(*) FROM xxx WHERE xxx.v = val1);
             RAISE NOTICE '%', rc;
             EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM xxx WHERE xxx.v = $1'
             USING val1 INTO rc;
             RAISE NOTICE '%', rc;
           END;
           $$;
NOTICE:  1
NOTICE:  1
DO
```

[`quote_literal()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is usually necessary for dynamic SQL, when you cannot use a `USING` clause. In your example:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM xxx WHERE xxx.v = ' || quote_literal(val1)
INTO ...
```

It protects against SQL injection and ensures proper escaping.

Modern releases have the [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) FROM xxx WHERE xxx.v = %L', val1) INTO ...
```

But `EXECUTE ... USING` should be preferred.

Comment: @Erwin I am using quote_literal liberally apart from other measures to protect from sql injection and other threats, but I would greatly appreciate if you could provide more pointers for the same. Thanks

Comment: @vedic: Pointers for how to protect against SQL injection? [This related answer has more details.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349) Or [try a search.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[plpgsql]+execute+%22sql+injection%22)